# Usar Double no método compareTo

Tags: java, comparação, números, double

Estou com uma dúvida.

Tenho varios métodos de comparação, porém, um dos atributos utilizados para fazer a comparação é double.

Aí ocorre um erro:

> Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double

Tentei converter o double para `String`. Porém ele ordena errado.

Ele ordena por ordem "alfabética".

Exemplo, ordena os valores assim:

```
10, 1000, 1002, 20, 30 , 300, 40.
```

Quando era pra ordenar assim:

```
10, 20 ,30 ,40 , 300, 1000 e 1002.
```

Aqui esta meu código:

```
<%! 
public static class Empreendimento implements Comparable<Empreendimento>{

// ignorar os construtores, métodos e atributos

// Para ordenar por Menor Preco
    public static void ordenaPorMenorPreco(List<Empreendimento> ArrayResultadoBusca) {
        Collections.sort(ArrayResultadoBusca, new Comparator<Empreendimento>() {
            //@Override
            public int compare(Empreendimento emp1, Empreendimento emp2) {
                return emp1.getPrecoMenor().compareTo(emp2.getPrecoMenor());
            }
        });
    }

%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O autoboxing não está de ajudando.

Tenta fazer assim:

```
return Double.valueOf(emp1.getPrecoMenor()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(emp2.getPrecoMenor()));
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Funcionou ! Muito obrigado ! Só uma duvida, o que seria esse autoboxing que você falou ?

Comment: @BrunoDM é a autoconversão de uma variável primitiva para uma variável de um objeto, o inverso se chama autounboxing. Isso serve para trabalhar com objetos e tipos primitivos de forma mais prática.

Comment: É a conversão automática que o compilador java faz entre primitivos e seus wrappers. Em resumo. Double d = 0; pode ser tratado como primitivo. Veja detalhes no [site da oracle.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Só uma sugestão, @BrunoDM. Talvez fosse interessante usar `Double` no campo e não `double`. Aí funcionaria conforme esperado sem a necessidade de converter sempre que for comparar.

Answer (score 4):

Como pode-se ver na mensagem de erro:

> Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double

Você está tentando acessar um método em um tipo primitivo, mas tipos primitivos não tem métodos, somente os objetos. Você está trabalhando como se estivesse usando o objeto da classe wrapper `Double` ao invés do tipo primitivo `double`.

Você tem três formas de resolver isso:

- Mudar tanto o retorno do método `getPrecoMenor` quanto a variável que ela retorna; ou
- Fazer a conversão na hora que for comparar, igual sugerido na outra resposta; ou ainda
- Ao invés de usar o método `compareTo()` poderia fazer assim:

  ```
  return emp1.getD() > emp2.getD() ? 1 : emp1.getD() < emp2.getD() ? -1 : 0 ;
  ```

Que é basicamente a mesma solução do @Thiago, mas usando dois operadores condicionais ternários. Fica menos legível mas fica mais compacto, deixando a critério do desenvolvedor qual melhor lhe atende.

A terceira opção se dá pois o método `compareTo()`, de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo(java.lang.Double)), retorna:

> the value 0 if anotherDouble is numerically equal to this Double; a value less than 0 if this Double is numerically less than anotherDouble; and a value greater than 0 if this Double is numerically greater than anotherDouble.

Em tradução livre, o método retorna:

> o valor 0 se o outro double é numericamente igual ao do objeto que invocou o método; um valor menor que 0 se o valor for menor que o outro double; e um valor maior que 0 se ele for maior que o outro.

Comment: Muito boa esta opção **return emp1.getPrecoMenor() - emp2.getPrecoMenor();** ! Nunca havia pensado desta forma!

Comment: Pois é, enquanto o método `compareTo()` na verdade só retorna `0`, `1` e `-1`, para efeitos práticos costuma dar o mesmo resultado, a não ser que você esteja usando o retorno do método de uma maneira muito específica para dar algum problema. Mas se for levar em conta a documentação em nenhum momento eles afirmam que o valor serão esses, só diz que será 0, positivo ou negativo, então tá valendo.

Comment: @Math Eu *acho* que nem sempre essa solução funciona, pelo menos não se forem números quebrados. O problema é que o Java vai converter o resultado pra `int`. Por exemplo, eu acabei de testar aqui `(int) (0.1 - 0.11)` e retorna `0` (zero), sendo que o esperado seria `-1` já que `0.1 < 0.11`.

Comment: @utluiz oh crap! Valeu por avisar, vou fazer uns testes aqui.

Comment: @utluiz arredondei para tentar contornar a situação, em um teste que eu fiz deu certo, mas algo me diz que isso não tá muito legal, olha só: https://ideone.com/hze5sl

Comment: @utluiz não vi nenhuma opção melhor a fazer do que retirar aquilo. Para não retirar meu terceiro bullet por completo fiz uma comparação com operadores ternários, para não ficar igual ao do Thiago. Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
     Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<Empreendimento>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Empreendimento o1, Empreendimento o2) {
            if(o1.getPrecoMenor() > o2.getPrecoMenor()){
                return 1;
            }else if(o1.getPrecoMenor() < o2.getPrecoMenor()){
                return -1;
            }else 
                return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Esta parece ser a melhor resposta, no sentido de que não envolve a criação de outras classes nem conversão de tipo desnecessária.